# errorCode=003001; statusCode=403; source=Throttling Policy

Tags: throttling, intuit-partner-platform

Lately, in our app using IPP data services, we have encountered these errors from time to time.

```
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
  <Error RequestId="49f7926a9aa84cfc8289534801dee72d">
    <RequestName>ErrorRequest</RequestName>
    <ProcessedTime>2012-12-07T10:10:59+00:00</ProcessedTime>
    <ErrorCode>3001</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDesc>message=This client has made too many consecutive requests over too short a period of time.  Please wait a short amount of time before attempting to submit again; errorCode=003001; statusCode=403; source=Throttling Policy</ErrorDesc>
  </Error>
</RestResponse>
```

Can't find any reference to a "Throttling Policy" or error code "3001" anywhere in the IPP documentation.

Any help in figuring out what the throttling limits are would be appreciated. Are they based around an IP, rate limitation, concurrency limitation, OAuth consumer, OAuth client, something else perhaps?

EDIT: Link to IDN forums about the same issue: https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=69&threadid=18910.

Comment: what is your question? What are the throttling limits, how to deal with the error, or something else?

Comment: I would like to know what the throttling limits are. Are they based around an IP, OAuth consumer token or OAuth client token?

Comment: +1 - Would like to know this as well.

Comment: Sounds like you should be performing a more efficient user query rather than 600+ per minute individual queries. Can you explain more of the use case and we can point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a throttling process in place if > 500 requests per minute by a single user or against a single realm.

You had over 600 requests during the one minute period.

Looks like almost all (all except 32 requests) were individual customer queries… all different customer record ids. Is there a way you can make a single customer list query, filtered if necessary, to get a bunch of customer records in a single request and reduce the number of calls you are making.